# iOS7 Mobile Safari: JavaScript Audio playback with DataURI

Tags: javascript, ios, audio

I try to play a wave audio file, which is read by a php-script.
I had success with the following code:

```js
var audio = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64," + wav_audio);
audio.play();
```

wav_audio ist the base64-encoded content of the wave audio file, which is the responseText of the php-script.
It's working with both Firefox and Safari, but not with Mobile Safari.
Every time I try to play the audio, I get an error: "The operation could not be completed".
My test device is an iPad 3 running iOS7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am also getting same issue i resolved by giving direct path of audio